# Ordering when using scipys Jenson Shannon distance

Tags: kullback-leibler, scipy, synthetic-data

I am currently the [scipy implementation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.jensenshannon.html) of the Jenson-Dhannon distance to compare 2 vectors sampled from 2 distributions.

I'd expect the distance to be zero if I get the same samples - regardless of the order of my samples; this does however not apply:

```py
a = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.7])

b = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.7])

c = np.array([0.2,0.7,0.1])

print(scipy.spatial.distance.jensenshannon(a,b))
# 0.0
print(scipy.spatial.distance.jensenshannon(a,c))
# 0.4567211416577999
```

The original application would be the quality measurement of synthetic data.

My use case is as follows:

> I have an original data vector and a synthesized data vector and want
> to compare them to asses whether my synthetic vector is close to the
> original distribution of my original vector. As I randomly sample each
> entry from the distributions, the two vectors will not align.

Am I missing something here or is this metric simply not suited for my use case? Or would it make sense to sort my samples beforehand? I have yet to find any application note that matches my use case.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.jensenshannon.html) states the arguments are "probability vectors," so *by definition* order matters.  This generalizes the distinction between a Bernoulli(p) and Bernoulli(1-p) variable: it matters whether the $p$ is the chance of heads or tails!  It's unclear what your "use case might be," because you haven't described it.

Comment: @whuber thank you for your comment. I have updated my question to include a more detailed explanation of what I am trying to do.

Comment: Could you clarify what a "data vector" is or represents?  Your code treats it as something else: namely, either a probability or frequency vector--but not as anything recognizable as "data."

Comment: @whuber It would be vector(s) of float vales. In my specific case its medical patient data, such as blood pressure. This shouldn't matter as far as I've understood since the implementation will normalize to 1 anyway.

Comment: That matters immensely, because it implies your code is invalid.  The arguments must be *probabilities* or *frequencies,* not blood pressures!  Normalizing blood pressures (or anything else) to sum to unity doesn't make them probabilities and doesn't lead to anything meaningful in this instance.

Comment: @whuber This makes a lot of sense, I finally got it,  thank you for clarifying. Feel free to post this as the answer, I will accept it.